# Migrate Jira to MySql - Unknown system variable 'storage_engine'

Tags: mysql, innodb, migration, storage-engine

I'm migrating JIRA in Windows from HSQL to MySQL and I got stuck with  the message `Unknown system variable 'storage_engine'`. Though I created a backup, installed MySQL and copied J connector to libs of JIRA.

Then I set the system variable `storage_engine = InnoDB` and rebooted the machine but the message is still there.

Could you please point me to a good direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 5.6, InnoDB is already the default.

Please do not use [storage-engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_storage_engine) because it is deprecated and probably explains the error.

You should use [default-storage-engine or default_storage_engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_default-storage-engine) in `my.cnf` instead

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine = InnoDB
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Answer (score 4):

[It' already a known Issue in Confluence Docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/Confluence+fails+to+start+with+error+%27Unknown+system+variable+%27storage_engine%27%27+using+MySQL+5.7.x):

> 1. Stop Confluence
> 2. Edit `<confluence-home>/confluence.cfg.xml`
> 3. Look for a line similar to:
>
>    ```
>    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/confluence?sessionVariables=storage_engine%3DInnoDB&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8</property>
>    ```
> 4. Remove `storage_engine%3DInnoDB&` from the line, it should look like:
>
>    ```
>    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/confluence?sessionVariables=useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8</property>
>    ```
> 5. Start Confluence

Comment: This is for confluence, not jira.

Answer (score 2):

If using Mysql 7 and Jira 7 change the connection string in the mysql.properties file.

```
sudo vi ${JIRA_APPLICATION_DIR}/atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/database-defaults/mysql.properties
```

Find the line starting with **databaseUrl=**

```
databaseUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost/jira?autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true&sessionVariables=storage_engine=InnoDB
```

and remove

```
&sessionVariables=storage_engine=InnoDB
```

Save the file and restart jira (Ubuntu 16.04 or any linux)

```
sudo service jira restart
```